# Pandas, строку из одного столбца превратить во множество и записать в другой столбец

Tags: python, pandas, list, set

Есть датафрейм вида:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'COL1': ['Строка 1', 'Строка 2', 'Строка 3', 'Строка 4'], 'COL2': ['a1, a2, a1', 'd2, d2', 'k1, T3', 'M7'], 'COL3': ['', '', '', ''],
 })
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в столбец 'COL3' скопировать только уникальные значения из столбца 'COL2'? Тоесть должно получиться:

[image: Итоговый результат]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, придётся разбить ваши строки по запятой с пробелом, а потом обратно склеить. И порядок следования элементов в множестве может поменяться:

```py
df['COL3'] = df['COL2'].map(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x.split(', '))))
```

Или даже лучше вот так, без ухода в `lambda`, чисто пандасом:

```py
df['COL3'] = df['COL2'].str.split(',\s*').map(set).str.join(', ')
```

| index | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Строка 1 | a1, a2, a1 | a1, a2 |
| 1 | Строка 2 | d2, d2 | d2 |
| 2 | Строка 3 | k1, T3 | T3, k1 |
| 3 | Строка 4 | M7 | M7 |

Есть и другие варианты, но пример я вам показал.